# How would I prevent my recursive Fibonacci sequence from generating a value past 4,000,000?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public class EvenFibonacciNumbers {
//0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int index = 0;
        while (true){
            System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
            index++;
        }
    }
    public static long fibonacci(int i){ //i is our index value
        //We will do this by recursion.
        //We know that if our index is 0, it will return 0.
        if(i == 0) return 0;
        //We know that if our index is 1 or 2, it will return 1.
        if (i <= 2) return 1;
        //Now we need to determine what would happen if our index is greater
        //than 2.
        long fibTerm = fibonacci(i-1)+fibonacci(i-2);
        return fibTerm;
    }
}
```

What I think I have to do is change it to

```
   while (fibTerm<4000000)
```

However, when I do this I get an error telling me that it cannot find the variable fibTerm. So, maybe this would be the wrong way to do this? I don't know exactly.

Comment: FIrst of: **don't** do this. A recursive fibonacci-calculator will have a runtime of `O(n ^ 2)`, which will make the entire calculation extremely slow for larger `n`. This problem can easily be solved in a linear fashion. In addition the linear approach would simplify introducing an upper bound quite a lot.

Comment: @Paul An iteration would be a more practical approach?

Comment: Yes. You need far less memory, don't have any recursive method-calls, a way more efficient execution in terms of time required to terminate and it won't impact understandability of the code.

Comment: @Paul Thanks I will try this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a local variable `fibterm` to store the last result of your calculation, check if the result exceeds your limit `4000000` and then print the result.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int index = 0;
    long fibterm = 0;
    while ((fibterm = fibonacci(index++)) < 4000000){
        System.out.println(fibterm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, when I do this I am forced to cast fibonacci(index) to int. When I run it, I get a list of 0's.

Comment: Do you know why when I run this, the last value it gives me is: 5702887? Shouldn't this stop before it returns that value?

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.